# MySQL update a row if it exists, and insert if not, and general query advice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a personal project which is a browser based game, and I am currently working though old code, and trying to optimise and update everything. I have a lot of functions like the one below, which basically updates the players item amounts. When the item is used, the row is left in the db, but the amount is set to 0, then the amount is updated when the player buys/finds more of that item.

After searching on here I have an idea that something like 'update if exists' could work instead of using the COUNT query, and possibly a multi-query for the updates, but I am just not sure the best way to accomplish this, if possible.

The tables have an ID, which auto increments, but a player can have multiple rows in the tables, which I identify with userID.

I apologise if this is a newbish question, but I am self taught, and if you don't ask people who know what they are doing, you never learn the proper ways to do things :)

Also happy to get advice on the code in general.

```
function power_caps_to_loot($userID, $itemID, $amount, $itemName, $updateInv) {

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// check if user has any of items already
$query = "SELECT COUNT(itemID) from lootbag where userID = $userID AND itemID = $itemID";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$count = $row[0];

    // if user has/had some already update amount, else insert new row          
    if ($count > 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE lootbag SET amount = amount + $amount WHERE userID = $userID AND itemID = $itemID";
        $mysqli->query($query);
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO lootbag (itemID, userID, amount, itemName, type, sub_type) 
        VALUES ($itemID, $userID, $amount, '$itemName', 'Cyborg Power Capsule', 'cyb_power')";
        $mysqli->query($query);
    }

    // if item comes from inventory, update amount
    if ($updateInv == 1) {
        $query = "UPDATE inventory SET amount = amount - $amount WHERE userID = $userID AND itemID = $itemID";
        $mysqli->query($query);
    }

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I am working through the functions changing queries that involve user input to prepared statements. The function above is executed by another function that is properly sanitized. Would you recommend that functions not involving user input be changed also?

Comment: It's too risky to have queries that could contain unescaped data, and passing around escaped data is messy at best. You should be doing your escaping at the point of query execution so a quick audit will show all values are obviously properly escaped. If you're doing the escaping elsewhere, it's not obvious and could be broken. Use placeholders whenever possible, and if you can't, make what you're doing abundantly clear so it's easy to review the code and check it's okay.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, and explanation. Better safe than sorry I guess, I'll start changing over to prepared statements as I work through the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use on duplicate key update or "upsert"

```
insert into .... on duplicate key update col1 = values(col1) ...
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Set your indexs to not allow duplicates and that statement will handle the rest

```
INSERT INTO lootbag (itemID, userID, amount, itemName, type, sub_type) 
    VALUES ($itemID, $userID, $amount, '$itemName', 'Cyborg Power Capsule', 'cyb_power')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + values(amount)
```

should work, assuming you have a unique index on item ID and User ID

Comment: @Reebo In other words, there's no need to check first!

Comment: Hi, thank you. I don't have indexes on those columns, tbh I'm not sure how index works. I assume I could set them as index and still have more than 1 row with the same user id, but not with the same userid and item id? I'll have to look it up :)

Comment: have an index on itemid and user id together so the combination of them has to be unique

Comment: @exussum Thank you very much for you help. I guess that gives me a lot of work to do now :)

Comment: Managed to squash it down to this, after adding a unique index to userID and itemID as suggested. Works as advertised, thanks for your help. Thought I would post it up for anyone else that needs something similar.

`$query = "INSERT INTO lootbag (itemID, userID, amount, itemName, type, sub_type)
    VALUES ($itemID, $userID, $amount, '$itemName', 'Cyborg Power Capsule', 'cyb_power')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE amount = amount + values(amount);";
$query .= "UPDATE inventory SET amount = amount - $amount WHERE userID = $userID AND itemID = $itemID;";
    $mysqli->multi_query($query);`